# PHP backend for app - tricky thing I can not figure out

Tags: php, backend

I have a tricky question which has made me almost pull my hair out for a day or two.

This is the code I am working on and that I need some help with:

```
<?php

    function parseOccationData($occationsObject, $attributeName) {
        return $occationsObject->$attributeName;
    }

    function parseAttribute($attributeData, $attributeId) {
        foreach ($attributeData as $attr) {
            if ($attr->AttributeId == $attributeId) {
                return $attr;
            }
        }
    }

    function parseImageData($data) {
        $image = new stdClass();

        $image->Url = $data->Url;
        $image->Width = $data->Width;
        $image->Height = $data->Height;

        return $image;
    }

    function makeCleanJSON($products) {
        $newProducts = array();

        foreach ($products as $oldProduct) {
            $newProduct = new stdClass();

            $newProduct->Id = $oldProduct->Id;
            $newProduct->Name = $oldProduct->Name;

            // Image
            $newProduct->Image = parseImageData($oldProduct->Image);

            // Movie Url
            $newProduct->MovieUrl = $oldProduct->UrlName;

            // Phone number
            $newProduct->Phone = parseAttribute($oldProduct->Attributes->AttributeData, 145)->Value->Data;
            $newProduct->Phone = str_replace("(0)", "0", $newProduct->Phone);

            // Price
            $newProduct->Price = parseAttribute($oldProduct->Attributes->AttributeData, 106)->Value->Data;

            // Long Text
            $newProduct->LongText = parseAttribute($oldProduct->Attributes->AttributeData, 101)->Value->Data;

            // Short Text
            $newProduct->ShortText = parseAttribute($oldProduct->Attributes->AttributeData, 102)->Value->Data;

            // Start Date
            $newProduct->StartDate = $oldProduct->Occasions->OccasionObject->StartDate;

            // End Date
            $newProduct->EndDate = $oldProduct->Occasions->OccasionObject->EndDate;

            // Start Time
            $newProduct->StartTime = $oldProduct->Occasions->OccasionObject->StartTime;

            // Valid Days
            $newProduct->ValidDays = $oldProduct->Occasions->OccasionObject->ValidDays;

            // Arena Id
            $newProduct->ArenaId = $oldProduct->Occasions->OccasionObject->ArenaId;

            // Arena Name
            $newProduct->ArenaName = $oldProduct->Occasions->OccasionObject->ArenaName;

            $newProducts[] = $newProduct;
        }

        return $newProducts;
    }
?>
```

Background: From an api call I get a long and tedious php array. I have a function that strips this array down to a minimum and after that, saves it as json and puts it in a file on a server.

Among other thing, it stores the object "Occasions". My code (I am making an app using this data) works fine, as long as there is only ONE occasion.

However, sometimes "occasions" consists of an array holding numerous objects.
When so, several fields in the app are blank.

I want to be able to make a check = if "occasions" holds more than one occation = loop through them all and pull the data I need from it.

This is a sample of the original data, when it holds just one occasion:

```
"Occasions":{  
     "OccasionObject":{  
        "Id":19926396,
        "AttributeId":111,
        "ProductId":603298,
        "OrganizationId":1045,
        "StartDate":"2014-12-10T00:00:00",
        "EndDate":"2014-12-11T00:00:00",
        "StartTime":"0001-01-01T19:00:00",
        "EndTime":"0001-01-01T19:00:00",
        "ValidDays":"Wednesday Thursday",
        "ArenaId":55,
        "ArenaName":"Rum",
        "EntryTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"
     }
},
```

And this is a sample of when it holds many:

```
"Occasions":{  
     "OccasionObject":[  
        {  
           "Id":19553154,
           "AttributeId":111,
           "ProductId":685680,
           "OrganizationId":1045,
           "StartDate":"2014-09-21T00:00:00",
           "EndDate":"2014-10-30T00:00:00",
           "StartTime":"0001-01-01T12:00:00",
           "EndTime":"0001-01-01T17:00:00",
           "ValidDays":"Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday",
           "ArenaId":55,
           "ArenaName":"Rum",
           "EntryTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {  
           "Id":19553155,
           "AttributeId":111,
           "ProductId":685680,
           "OrganizationId":1045,
           "StartDate":"2014-10-31T00:00:00",
           "EndDate":"2014-10-31T00:00:00",
           "StartTime":"0001-01-01T12:00:00",
           "EndTime":"0001-01-01T16:00:00",
           "ValidDays":"Friday",
           "ArenaId":555,
           "ArenaName":"Rum",
           "EntryTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        }
]
```

So, in the case of when only one occasion, this is part of the final json (looking the way I want it to):

```
{
    "Id": 11,
    "Name": "Moviename",
    "Image": {
        "Width": 214,
        "Height": 317
    },
    "Phone": "05504-345",
    "Price": "4 biljons",
    "LongText": "Yes a long text",
    "ShortText": "Yes, short",
    "StartDate": "2014-11-12T00:00:00",
    "EndDate": "2014-11-13T00:00:00",
    "StartTime": "0001-01-01T19:00:00",
    "ValidDays": "Wednesday Thursday",
    "ArenaId": 55,
    "ArenaName": "Rum"
},
```

However when several occations, the fields StartDate, EndDate, StartTime, ValidDays, ArenaId, ArenaName all are empty.

So I need to alter my coding so that it accepts both one and several occasions. I can not figure out how to do it!

Comment: Why don't you set it so that "OccasionObject" is always an array?  If there's only one object, the array would be size 1.

Comment: If there is more than one occasion, what will the output look like?